# 3 legged oauth (RSA-SHA1) imap gmail authentication - JAVA

Tags: oauth, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

Problem:

I want to use 3 legged oauth using RSA-SHA1 authentication for an Imap client with google.

I have the access_token for a user. I've successfully grabbed the tokens, authenticated with google and grabbed an acess token. I know this access token is correct because I can correctly parse and read the Contacts api.

I am having trouble with the imap (javamail-1.4.4) and RSA-SHA1 authentication and google.

The examples are only for HMAC-SHA1. Has anyone figured out how to use RSA-SHA1 with google and successfully connect to their api and read emails ? Note that all I have is a saved access_token.

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail doesn't support OAUTH.  If you can find a SASL provider that supports OAUTH, JavaMail might be able to use that SASL provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google provides an example for this: http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode

Comment: hmmm... I think you did not understand the question. I need 3 legged oauth, not 2 legged. I also need to use RSA-SHA1 not HMAC-SHA1 which is the java examples as mentioned in the question. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I think you just have to adapt the code. Check the class: XoauthSaslResponseBuilder. You need to update the signature from HMAC-SHA1 to RSA-SHA1. Adapt also the parameter inside XoauthAuthenticator to match the 3 legged example: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html. The OAuth libary will do the work for the signature.